# Load webpages in greyscale or sepia mode Automatically in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, css

I have recently tried a new web browser `Vivaldi` beta version. It has an inbuilt feature that allows webpages to be loaded in greyscale or sepia mode. It is pretty handy for easy and less distracting reading and browsing websites.

Here is an example:
[image: Vivaldi browser's Sepia Mode]

Does Google Chrome has similar feature? Are there any extension that can do similar effects?

Comment: I just Googled "greyscale chrome". The first result is called [Grayscale Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grayscale-tool/odolflphhameojgliipcnahnipmogigo?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Burgi. I found that too. But it does not have Sepia filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decreased-productivity/nlbpiflhmdcklcbihngeffpmoklbiooj

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/care-your-eyes/fidmpnedniahpnkeomejhnepmbdamlhl

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/artsy-head-effects/pfkpbepcdlefnmjilnfcfbbnkplokmli

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-filter-effects/apnbkmkpchabofhbnmhbdbnlpkbcomkg

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/read-mode/nagcaahojecfeopbghgihcabgiepploa/reviews

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sheen/mopkplcglehjfbedbngcglkmajhflnjk

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/night-reading-mode/chcciiimjmlgcoabgfdhkfjdcgfpgndi

And of course Readability , and dozens of userstyles, userscripts and bookmarklets.

If you don't want dozens of extension in Chrome, just install 
the few extensions you use into Vivaldi.

As features from classic Opera are implemented in Vivaldi, 
the number of extension you'd need in Chrome or the new Opera 
would just keep growing to match the features.